# Which is more informal?

Tags: grammar

Which is more informal?

> 1. Neither Alex nor my other friends care about their future.
> 2. Neither my other friends nor Alex care about their future.
> 3. Neither my other friends nor Alex cares about their future.

Comment: Your choice beteen 2 and 3 is not about formality, but about what is correct (*care/cares*)

Answer (score 1):

Neither/nor is never informal. The real question is, what's different about Alex? Why can't you just say:

> None of my friends care about their future.

If Alex really is so important, and you want to keep it informal, you could say

> Alex doesn't care about his future, and none of my other friends do either.

or slightly less informal:

> Alex doesn't care about his future, and nor do my other friends.